# OpenCV defocus blur with custom kernel?

Tags: opencv, kernel, blur

I would like to simulate defocus blur, the intensity for each pixel in an image is:

1/(pi*r^2) for a given radius r, if the pixel is within sqrt(x^2+y^2) and 0 if not
(see code for better explanation)

This gives a blur/convolution kernel in a circular shape. 
I tried to do this in opencv bu had no luck: opencv just "pixelizes" the edges of my image: 
[testimage http://www.bilderkiste.org/show/original/1131895735815/test_out.jpg](http://www.bilderkiste.org/show/original/1131895735815/test_out.jpg)

I can't really figure out why this is happening, here's my code so far:

```
//includes. then:
using namespace std;
#define KERNELLENGTH 3
#define PI 3.14159265
int main() {
    IplImage *src = 0;
    IplImage *dst = 0;
    src = cvLoadImage("test.bmp"); //create image matrixes..
    dst = cvLoadImage("test.bmp"); //
    CvMat *filter;
    double kernel[KERNELLENGTH * KERNELLENGTH]; //create an appropriate kernel
    int r = KERNELLENGTH / 2; //calculate the radius
    double value = 1 / (PI * KERNELLENGTH * KERNELLENGTH / (4 * r)); //calculate the defocus blur value
    cout << "Kernel:" << "\n";
    for (int x = 0; x < KERNELLENGTH; x++) //calculate kernel (seems to work right!)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < KERNELLENGTH; y++) {
            if (sqrt((x - KERNELLENGTH / 2) * (x - KERNELLENGTH / 2) + (y
                    - KERNELLENGTH / 2) * (y - KERNELLENGTH / 2)) <= r) {
                kernel[y * 4 + x] = value; //Wert zuweisen
                cout << value << "\t";
            } else
                cout << 0 << "\t";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    filter = cvCreateMatHeader(KERNELLENGTH, KERNELLENGTH, CV_32FC1);//create the filter
    cvSetData(filter, kernel, KERNELLENGTH * sizeof(kernel[0]));//link kernel and filter
    cvFilter2D(src, //convolve filter and src, save to dst
            dst, filter, cvPoint(-1, -1));

    cvSaveImage("test_out.bmp", dst); //save dst on disk

    cvReleaseImage(&src);
    cvReleaseImage(&dst);
    return 0;
}
```

I would really appreciate some help with this, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is in `#define KERNELLENGTH 3`, as you get `KERNELLENGTH / 2 == 1` and the kernel is 3-by-3 something, which I wouldn't call a proper defocus disk.

Have you tested with e.g. `#define KERNELLENGTH 10`?